# SSRS Sub Report visibility based on whether it is selected from a main report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a Main report which has 3/4 sub reports within it (1st level sub reports). One of those sub reports has another sub report within that (we'll call that 2nd level Sub report).

What I'm trying to do is to hide the 2nd level sub report when the Main Report is ran but if the 1st level sub report is run by it's self then the 2nd level sub report will show.

Essentially the Main Report needs to show "Highlights" of the 1st level Sub reports and only by going into the 1st level sub reports directly will more information (2nd level sub report) be shown.

Is that possible with using parameters/visibility?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have a hidden parameter that passes a "hide" parameter to another hidden parameter on subreport 1, that has a default value of "don't hide"? Then you can easily parmetrise the visibility of the other subreport.

Comment: @Larnu Can you explain where the first hidden parameter would be? On the Main report or on the 2nd level sub report?

Comment: It would be on what you refer to as the "main" and "1st".

Comment: @Larnu took me a bit of time but got there, thanks for the help, it is now working as I planned.